# Does my fictional use of Arabic honorifics match real-word usage?

Tags: arabic, titles

I asked [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/172028/titles-and-honorifics-for-a-female-only-quasi-islamic-society) on the World Building Stack Exchange yesterday. My question was closed fairly quickly, but people seemed to think that, nevertheless, it was an interesting question, and someone suggested that I ask a related question on this site instead.

I'm building a fictional universe in which there is a female-only quasi-Islamic order of chivalry. Members of this order are divided in three grades:

1. The highest grade comes with the honorific ***ma'ali***, and this actually forms a part of the recipient's name, e.g. **Ma'ali Jane Smith**. A recipient of this grade would be granted addressed, and also referred to in the third person, as **Ma'ali Jane**.
2. The middle grade comes with the honorific ***alsayidat***. A recipient of this grade would be addressed, and also referred to in the third person, as **Alsayidat Jane**.
3. The lowest grade comes with the honorific ***anisa***. A recipient of this grade would be addressed, and also referred to in the third person, as **Anisa Jane**.

**How well does my fictional use of the above honorifics match real-world usage, present and/or past?** If it doesn't match, is it at least a plausible adaptation of past or present practices?

Comment: You need to use feminine endings consistently:  AH or AT.  The T is usually silent in modern Arabic, but might be pronounced in very formal usage.

Comment: @BertBarrois Thank you. It felt, intuitively, like *alsayidat* should be *alsayida*, but Google Translate had its little heart on translating "Mrs" as "Alsayidat". If I change *alsayidat* to *alsayida*, will I have achieved consistency? I read that *ma'ali* is the same for both men and women. Is that correct?

Comment: @BertBarrois On a related note: you mention Arabic sometimes having a silent *t*. Are historical spellings a thing in Arabic? (I'd read that Arabic script is very phonetic, but obviously I know very little about it.)

Comment: Even in classical Arabic, the T was silent before a natural pause.  In modern, it is generally silent except in run-on phrases such as title+name or noun+possessive.  If your fiction is futuristic, I'd use AH consistently:  *ma`āliyah, al-sayyidah, ānisah*.  The prefix written AL- assimilates phonetically to S, so the word would be pronounce *as-sayyidah*.

Comment: @BertBarrois - The assimilating _al-_ prefix in Arabic means 'the' - would it really be used in _addressing_ someone, or would she just be addressed as _sayyida Fatima_? (She would likely be properly _referred_ to as _al-sayyida Fatima_, but not _called_ that to her face.)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin So, if I've read you correctly, current usage is to *address* some, in the second person, as "sayyida Fatima", but to *refer* to her as "al-sayyida Fatima"? Or am I tying myself in knots? What about *anisa*? Is current usage to address someone as "anisa Fatima", but to refer to her as "al-anisa Fatima"?

Comment: @TomHosker - I _believe_ that you've described current usage correctly; my knowledge of Arabic is mostly along the lines of having _read about_ the language, rather than attempts to _learn to read and speak_ it. Also consider the analogous situation in English - you might refer to "the Lord John Smith", but you would call him " Lord John" to his face.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thank you ever so much. As far as you know, is it normal in Arabic to use an honorific with someone's *first* name, rather than the surname?

Comment: @TomHosker - That's likely to be contextually dependent, and I don't have enough information on the context; I was merely following your lead in the question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Of course. What I mean is: in either British or American English, addressing John Smith as "Mr John" would always be jarring. (My wife is Filipino, and it always makes me chuckle when *she* does it!) But using the standard honorifics with a first name - *at least in some contexts* - would be normal in Arabic? (I'm just trying to *borrow* from Arabic in a rational and informed manner, not re-create the language and culture!)

Comment: @TomHosker - Again, I _believe_ so; it would depend on the particular honorific and the context in which it is being used. An honorific that translates as the equivalent of "Mr." might not be used with a given name; one that translates as the equivalent of "Lord" or "Sir (knight)" might be. It might also depend on the particular Arabic-speaking culture; not all of them necessarily _have_ surnames.

Comment: @TomHosker - That, incidentally, is why Thais and Filipinos (among others) often use "Mr. John"; there are large subsegments of the population that simply don't have/use surnames.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thank you, again. One last question: what about *ma'ali*? I've done my best to extrapolate from [Her Excellency Reem Ebrahim Al Hashimy's profile page](https://www.mofaic.gov.ae/en/the-ministry/the-ministers/uae-minister-of-state-for-international-cooperation/minister-of-the-state-for-international-cooperation): it's in Arabic and English. If I happened to bump into Her Excellency in downtown Dubai, and if my Arabic was otherwise impeccable, would it be correct for me to address her as "Ma'ali Reem"?

Comment: @TomHosker - Beyond my level of knowledge of the language, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin No worries. You went above and beyond the call of duty several comments ago!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding ma'ali, you've used it correctly in "Ma'ali Jane Smith". And yes if you bump into her in downtown Dubai you can use ma'ali, but now since you're talking with her directly you'd say ma'aliki Jane (your honor).

Secondly, as @Bert said in the comments, it should be as-sayida instead of al-sayidat. Without boring you too much with the grammar of it all, the t at the end of al-sayidat would be silent unless we're talking in Standard Arabic, and since it seems that you're building a futuristic world, I don't think you need to worry about that. Just stick with as-sayida. Now if you wanna pluralize it, put the t back at the end. as-sayidat (the ladies) is the plural.
If you bump into ***a*** sayida (notice it doesn't have the `as-` article here), you'd say sayidati (my lady).

Anisa sounds all good. You'd use anisati while talking with an anisa. Nisa' (نساء if you ever wanna look that up) is the plural, and al-anisa if you wanna use an article.

> Do they fit the real-world usages?

Absolutely! Well... I don't think I've ever heard of a sayida these days, but it's usage as an honorific is definitely still used. So don't worry, it won't stick out.

And as a side tip, use almaany.com instead of google translate. It's much more accurate.

Comment: By the way, this sounds like a fun project you're working on. I'd be interested to know more.